# Are there terms for adjectives that imply or exclude totality?

Tags: adjectives

When I hear *waterproof*, I think "water definitely can't get in." To me, that's an adjective that implies totality (for my ignorance of a better term).

When I hear *water-resistant*, I think "water won't get in easily, but it's definitely not waterproof." To me, that phrase *excludes* totality.

Are there terms for these different types of adjectives that imply or exclude totality?

And is there a term for adjectives that do neither of these things and describe, I guess, the full range of a quality?

Comment: _Water-resistant_ shouldn't exclude _water-proof_. The set of "Water-proof" things is a sub-set of the "Water-resistant" things in the universe; _water-resistant_ covers a range beginning at the smallest degree of resistance to water, and reaching all the way to 100% resistance, which is equal to _water-proof_.

Comment: @Conrado I thought about that... but my intuition is that "water-resistant" is used in contrast to "water-proof". For example, when buying hiking boots I knew I wanted "water-proof" because boots marketed as "water-resistant" definitely weren't waterproof - otherwise the seller would have marked them as such. So in a vacuum, does water-resistant include water-proof? Maybe. But not in general usage, or at least in this one example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Adjective Gradability**
>
> Adjectives describe qualities (characteristics) of nouns. Some
>   qualities can vary in intensity or "grade", for example:
>
> *rather hot, hot, very hot; hot, hotter, the hottest* The adjective *hot*
>   is **gradable**.
>
> Other qualities cannot vary in intensity or grade because they are:
>
> - **extremes** (for example: *freezing*)
> - **absolutes** (for example: *dead*)
> - **classifying** (for example: *nuclear*)
>
> The adjectives *freezing*, *dead* and *nuclear* are **non-gradable**.

(From [EnglishClub](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/adjectives-gradability.htm))

'Waterproof' is probably best seen as at the (idealised?) end of a continuum of water resistance, so I'd probably go with '*extreme*' here (although 'absolute' is arguably true also.)

Comment: +1 "idealised"-- ideally, then, absolutes are the adjectives indicating one end or the other of the continuum referred to by a gradeable adjective?

Comment: Yep, I can see how _waterproof_, idealized, is an absolute but is probably actually just an extreme. The example of _dead_ helps bring that into perspective.

Comment: EnglishClub's example of an absolute-type adjective, 'dead', is meant to show an either - or situation. Even here, there are grey areas, hinging on definitions of death. Perhaps 'unique' in its original sense is a less problematic example. // Their example of an _extreme adjective_ is arguably equally 'either - or',  but you can get as close as physically possible to 'freezing': there's a continuous temperature scale. (Of course, the word is often used loosely, too.) So, as you say, { ... moderately cold ... quite cold ... cold ... very cold ... nearly freezing ... v close to freezing ... l>}

Comment: 'Unique' in its traditional / default 'only one example' sense is on a scale of sorts (100 left ... 50 left ... 10 ... 5 4 3 2 ...it's unique.), but not a continuous scale. _Classifying adjectives_ are far easier to distinguish: chemical, Roman .... They can merge with attributive nouns. Is 'steel' in 'a steel bridge' an adjective or noun? (The jury was out, last I heard.) [Comments following on from Conrado's]

Comment: Great clarifications. I just wanted to point out [this paper](http://semantics.uchicago.edu/kennedy/docs/vg-epub.pdf), which argues that some gradable adjectives are "absolute gradables", marking "a maximal [or, non-zero] degree of the measured concept." _Waterproof_ seems to fit the "maximal" description, and _water-resistant_ seems to fit the "non-zero" description.

Answer (score -1):

This is taken into account in a grammatical classification of adjectives: [ref.](https://linguapress.com/grammar/adjectives.htm); the two classes describing the characteritics in question are the **absolute** adjectives (waterproof) and the **gradable** adjectives (water-resistant). This means that you might be able to say "very water-resistant" but not "very waterproof". In fact, you can say both: [ref. 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+water-resistant&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20water%20-%20resistant%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cvery%20water%20-%20resistant%3B%2Cc0), [ref. 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+waterproof&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20waterproof%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cvery%20waterproof%3B%2Cc0).