# An idiom for overzealous neophytes

Tags: idiom-requests

Does English have any idioms for the tendency of many neophytes to try to be more Catholic than the Pope? (not necessarily in a religious sense only)

Comment: There's a phrase "the zeal of the new convert", but AFAIK it is mostly used to refer to religious zeal.

Comment: For some reason "bright-eyed and bushy-tailed" comes to mind, though it doesn't work with zealousness or strict adherence.

Comment: I was thinking of "eager beaver", but none of the sources I found say that it's about a neophyte, it's just anyone really enthusiastic.

Comment: If you can provide the full context in which you plan to use the word, that would be helpful.

Comment: Often a nonce verb with a cognate object is created: "[He is/they are trying to] out-pope the Pope"; "out-professor the professor"; out-program the programmer", etc.

Comment: I can’t think of a word for it, but “pace yourself” might be the response.

Comment: [Zeal of the Convert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeal_of_the_convert) has a wikipedia page but does mostly seem to be about religion, especially Islam.

Answer (score 4):

> The phrase **a new broom sweeps clean** means that a newly appointed
> person tends to make far-reaching changes or that changes are made
> energetically by [them].

[[Testbook](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532601/are-there-terms-for-adjectives-that-imply-or-exclude-totality/532603#532603)]

Neophytes in general, not just new appointees, are acceptable tenors (the people referred to).

But change, especially sweeping change, is not always for the better. A balanced view expressing this caveat, the full proverb, is given by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_new_broom_sweeps_clean,_but_an_old_broom_knows_the_corners):

> - **a new broom sweeps clean, but an old broom knows the corners**
>
> New management imposes radical changes, but those with prior
> experience have more knowledge.