# Is there a term to describe the use of an incorrect adverb (as an adjective-modifier)?

Tags: grammar, terminology, rhetorical-devices

The phrase 'slightly dead' would be incorrect because a person can't be 'slightly' dead. Is there a term to describe phrases that incorrectly use adverbs in this way?

Comment: This is trying to grade the ungradable, Jonathan. See [Are there terms for adjectives that imply or exclude totality?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532601/are-there-terms-for-adjectives-that-imply-or-exclude-totality/532603#532603). 'Dead' is an absolute, and resists grading (few adjectives disallow it entirely: 'dead as a doornail' / 'quite dead'). // *'A very chemical reaction' ('chemical' is a classifying adjective). // *'It was very enormous' ('enormous' is an extreme adjective).

Comment: You could easily use *slightly dead* if you were going for a humorous effect. The "rules" of English don't necessarily apply to witty remarks. Cf. The Munchkins' triumph song in the classic film of "The Wizard of Oz" in which they sing of the Wicked Witch of the East: "She isn't only merely dead / she's really most sincerely dead." In your case, "slightly dead" could be an understated remark intended to call attention to an obvious fact in a dry or sarcastic way.

Comment: @Robusto Are you sure that's not G & S!?

Comment: There's a term for *saying* "The phrase 'slightly dead' [is] incorrect" - that's ***pedantry***.  And no-one could possibly take issue with (admittedly, figurative) *The acoustics of the room were slightly dead*. That's not to mention @Robusto's point about *facetious* usages.

Comment: 'Gradable adjectives' are what I am after. Many thanks Edwin.

Answer (score 1):

**[contradictory premises](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-contrast-composition-and-rhetoric-1689798#:%7E:text=Contradictory%20premises%20involve%20an%20argument,and%20denies%20the%20same%20thing.)** or a **[contradiction in terms](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/contradiction-in-terms)**

Your question appears to be driving at the same gist as an article published by Merriam-Webster in response to questions about the grammaticality or ungrammaticality of using the adverb "very" to modify the adjective "unique," given "unique" means "one of a kind" and so cannot be a matter of degrees as something either is one of a kind or isn't.

Merriam-Wester's explains that it's not an error in grammar but an *error in logic*, also known as a [**logical fallacy**](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-logical-fallacy-1691259#:%7E:text=A%20logical%20fallacy%20is%20an,logically%20from%20what%20preceded%20it.), and that errors in logic often get confused as being errors in grammar. That said, like commenters here in regard to your example, Merriam-Webster acknowledgesd that it's not uncommon to hear such usage, so an informal meaning has evolved as a result, what with it being English speakers *en masse* proscribing what is and isn't acceptable via common usage, not pedantic literati prescribing it from their ivy-covered ivory towers, though many do try. Nevertheless, here's the Merriam-Webster article:

> [Is It Wrong to Say 'Very Unique'?](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/very-unique-and-absolute-adjectives) The unusual case of 'unique'
> Adjectives make up about 20% of English words. Some are modified
> frequently: very heavy, extremely tall, mostly sunny, seriously
> flawed. But a substantial majority are rarely modified, not because of
> any grammatical rule, but simply because their meanings are so
> technical or specific that they don’t need to be: provable, midcourse,
> umbilical, ultraviolet. These words have narrow applications and often
> name a quality that does not exist in degrees. They are rarely used in
> the comparative or superlative, but this is a consequence of logic,
> not of grammar.
>
> 'Unique' is often cited as a word that should never be
> modified, as its original meanings were "being the only one" and
> "unequaled." But 'unique' has another meaning, "unusual," and it's
> common to modify the word when it's used this way.
>
> Needless to say, people confuse logic and grammar. Grammar is not
> logical. Nevertheless, some grammarians insist that certain
> adjectives, usually called “absolute adjectives,” can never be
> modified. The grammarian Joseph Wright, for example, in his A
> Philosophical Grammar of the English Language from 1838 (and like
> others before and since), gave a list of adjectives “which admit of no
> variation of state”—in other words, that cannot be modified. His list
> includes words like square, dead, entire, false, and obvious. And yet,
> evidence of actual usage shows that almost square, nearly dead, whole
> entire, mostly false, and plainly obvious are all commonly used and
> standard. Which would make him very angry.
>
> Another word in his list is excellent, and it’s true that this is a
> word that is seldom seen in the comparative, though the superlative
> most excellent is common. Arthur Conan Doyle modified excellent in a
> way that stands out to modern ears twice in the Sherlock Holmes
> stories—both times in words spoken by the Great Detective himself:
>
> “You would oblige me by bringing your very excellent field glass.”
> —Silver Blaze
>
> “Your advice is very excellent, Miss Harrison.” —The Naval Treaty
>
> Very excellent is a good example of a plausible but uncommon way to
> modify an adjective. It might not be a very necessary phrase, but
> that’s not the point: even Sherlock Holmes doesn’t apply logic to
> grammar. It’s a good thing that Philosophical is in the title of
> Wright’s book, since his list is more about ideals than linguistic
> reality. It’s a wish list.
>
> The ideal that these list makers wish to uphold has to do with the
> purest interpretation of the definition of a word. According to this
> idealistic interpretation, a square must have four right angles, or it
> is simply not a square; false must mean only and exactly “not true.”
> We know that neither word is always used in its absolute sense,
> however, since angles might be “nearly square” or an answer to a
> question might be “mostly false.” Life is not made up of absolutes,
> and language bends accordingly to accommodate. It does not break.
>
> Unique is often cited as a word that should never be modified, and it
> presents a special case because of the evolution of its meanings. It
> comes from the Latin word unus (“one”), and its original meanings in
> English were “being the only one” or “sole” and “having no like or
> equal” or “unequaled.” These meanings are about as absolute as they
> can be, and are seldom modified. However, words that are in widespread
> use have a tendency to take on extended meanings, and unique also came
> to mean something that was unusual or rare, as in “a unique
> opportunity” or “a unique feature.” The fact is, the original (and
> most absolute) meaning of unique is the word’s least commonly used
> meaning today (meaning “sole” or “only,” as in “the unique copy of my
> manuscript”). But modifying unique when it means “unusual” is common:
>
> The newest English sport is the race to create the most unique,
> high-concept specialty tea. —Raphael Kadushin, National Geographic
> Traveler, January 2012
>
> This is the on-the-mountain portion of the most unique partnership in
> skiing. —Barry Svrluga, The Washington Post, 10 October 2010
>
> The bacteria growing in and on the human body is so unique and so
> revealing that scientists believe germs will soon help catch bad guys.
> —Mandy Oaklander, TIME, 31 August 2015
>
> Our evidence shows that very unique is much more frequently used in
> spoken English than in professionally edited writing, which means that
> it is understood to be more informal and should be used with care.
> Though there is no strict rule of grammar that prevents modifying
> these adjectives, we must remember to be very careful.

Of the many types of errors in logic, this would be: [**contradictory premises**](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-contrast-composition-and-rhetoric-1689798#:%7E:text=Contradictory%20premises%20involve%20an%20argument,and%20denies%20the%20same%20thing.). A common expression for this is: [**contradiction in terms**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/contradiction-in-terms).